# How to animate on hovering image and text at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

here i am using html and css i want the image and text should animate(zoom-in and zoom-out) with 5s delay.

How can i do it? I am new to this.TIA

Here is what i tried so far where as for me only image is getting `animated` link to [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iepzl1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```css
.text-center :hover {
transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 pt-1 text-center">
        <a class="link">
            <img class="img-responsive " src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/321/200/300.jpg?hmac=1hjkl5WdcOOj525LK78s0QQQkN0b_qb1_xSacNQfMSk" alt="">
            <p class="text pt-2">Mytext</p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```css
.text-center {
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
}

 .text-center img {
     transition: all 5.0s;
 }

 .text-center :hover {
   transform: scale(1.5);
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 pt-1 text-center">
        <a class="link">
            <img class="img-responsive " src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/321/200/300.jpg?hmac=1hjkl5WdcOOj525LK78s0QQQkN0b_qb1_xSacNQfMSk" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
        <p class="text pt-2">Mytext</p>
</div>
```

I moved your `p` outside the `div` and added some CSS rules for the zoom effect.